# Color change animation for AR model

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, maya, arcore, mel

I want to make color animation for my 3d model. In those animation, only the color of the model changes. For example - Animation1 makes the color of model as Green, Animation2 makes it Red, and Animation3 makes the color Blue.

After making the changes I want to export animation along with the model in `.fbx` format.

Comment: This seems not to be an coding related question. Or do I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

### Quick animation

Launch Autodesk Maya, create a poly Cube, assign a Phong shader to it, and apply the following MEL script to this cube (you can do it by opening Script Editor and choosing MEL tab):

```
select -r pCube1 ;

currentTime 1 ;
setAttr "phong1.color" -type double3 1 0 0 ;
setKeyframe { "phong1.c" } ;

currentTime 61 ;
setAttr "phong1.color" -type double3 0 1 0 ;
setKeyframe { "phong1.c" } ;

currentTime 120 ;
setAttr "phong1.color" -type double3 0 0 1 ;
setKeyframe { "phong1.c" } ;
```

Press <kbd>execute</kbd> button.

### Output a texture

Make sure that Arnold library is loaded in Plug-in Manager. After applying color animation, setup scene's lights (you can use Maya or Arnold lights) and using main menu choose:

```
Arnold –> Utilities –> Render Selection To Texture
```

Save a sequence of UV-mapped images for a desired number of frames:

[image]

Resulted image sequence looks like this (I've used `OpenEXR` format here with res 512x512):

[image]

Now you can export your poly geometry in any desired file format that supports texturing and animation (do not forget to bake your asset or transform animation if animation is needed).

After that you can apply a rendered image sequence as a texture to your model in Unity.

### Further steps

Whether a target renderer supports image sequence for texture or video texture or not, depends entirely on that renderer for AR app (as we all know native Sceneform library isn't supported anymore since v17.1). Apple RealityKit framework, for example, supports VideoMaterials, so I can easily convert the resulted `.exr` image sequence into `h264` video file in Final Cut Pro X or in NUKE.